# Javascript bot prompts the user?

Tags: javascript, bots

I'm creating a simple javascript bot and I was wondering if there was any way to have the bot prompt the user. So it would say "Hey, how are you?" or something before the user types anything. I have the code below, help would be much appreciated!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var trigger = [
 ["hi","hey","hello"], 
 ["how are you", "how is life", "how are things"],
 ["what are you doing", "what is going on"]
];
var reply = [
 ["Hi","Hey","Hello"], 
 ["Fine", "Pretty well", "Fantastic"],
 ["Nothing much", "About to go to sleep", "Can you guest?", "I don't know actually"],
];

var alternative = ["Haha...", "Eh..."];
document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
 var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
 if(key === 13){ //Enter button
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = input;
  output(input);
 }
});
function output(input){
 try{
  var product = input + "=" + eval(input);
 } catch(e){
  var text = (input.toLowerCase()).replace(/[^\w\s\d]/gi, ""); //remove all chars except words, space and 
  text = text.replace(/ a /g, " ").replace(/i feel /g, "").replace(/whats/g, "what is").replace(/please /g, "").replace(/ please/g, "");
  if(compare(trigger, reply, text)){
   var product = compare(trigger, reply, text);
  } else {
   var product = alternative[Math.floor(Math.random()*alternative.length)];
  }
 }
 document.getElementById("system").innerHTML = product;
 speak(product);
 document.getElementById("input").value = ""; //clear input value
}
function compare(arr, array, string){
 var item;
 for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
  for(var y=0; y<array.length; y++){
   if(arr[x][y] == string){
    items = array[x];
    item =  items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
   }
  }
 }
 return item;
}

function speak(string){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mixed some of your code with a simple chatbot I worked on using jQuery. The response is still the same as your code. I just change the DOM manipulation.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="content"> 
            <p id="out">
            </p>
            <p id="inp">
                <span id="dir">Message: </span>
                <div id="stretchbox">
                    <input type="text" 
                           id="txt-inp"
                           autocomplete="off"             
                           autocorrect="off"
                           autocapitalize="off" 
                           autofocus="autofocus"
                           spellcheck="false">
                    </input>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function() {
            var trigger = [
              ["hi","hey","hello"], 
              ["how are you", "how is life", "how are things"],
              ["what are you doing", "what is going on"]
            ];
            var reply = [
              ["Hi","Hey","Hello"], 
              ["Fine", "Pretty well", "Fantastic"],
              ["Nothing much", "About to go to sleep", "Can you guest?", "I don't know actually"],
            ];

            println('Bot: ' + trigger[1][0]);

            var alternative = ["Haha...", "Eh..."];

            let textInput = $('#txt-inp');
            let messageOutput = $('#out');
            let processingStatus = $('<span>Bot: Processing...<br></span>');
            let name = 'cds1170';
            function println(text) {
              let newSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
              let newLine = document.createElement("BR");
              let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
              newSpan.appendChild(textNode);
              document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newSpan);
              document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newLine);
              gotoBottom();
            }
            function print(text) {
              let newSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
              let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
              newSpan.appendChild(textNode);
              document.getElementById("out").appendChild(newSpan);
            }
            function gotoBottom() {
              window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            }
            function sendMessage() {
              let data = {
                'reply': textInput.val()
              };
              if (!data['reply']) {
                return;
              }
              println(name + ': ' + data['reply']);
              textInput.val('');
              messageOutput.append(processingStatus);
              textInput.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              messageOutput.children().last().remove();
              textInput.removeAttr('disabled');
              output(data['reply']);
            }
            $('#txt-inp').keypress(function(e) {
              if (e.which == 13) {
                sendMessage();
              }
            });

            function output(input){
              try{
                var product = input + "=" + eval(input);
              } catch(e){
                var text = (input.toLowerCase()).replace(/[^\w\s\d]/gi, ""); //remove all chars except words, space and 
                text = text.replace(/ a /g, " ").replace(/i feel /g, "").replace(/whats/g, "what is").replace(/please /g, "").replace(/ please/g, "");
                if(compare(trigger, reply, text)){
                  var product = compare(trigger, reply, text);
                } else {
                  var product = alternative[Math.floor(Math.random()*alternative.length)];
                }
              }
              println(product);
            }

            function compare(arr, array, string){
              var item;
              for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
                for(var y=0; y<array.length; y++){
                  if(arr[x][y] == string){
                    items = array[x];
                    item =  items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
                  }
                }
              }
              return item;
            }
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update: I added some HTML elements that your code trying to find. I didn't change much in the your DOM manipulation. Will this work?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>


    <div id="user"></div>
    <div id="system"></div>
    <input id="input" type="text">

    <script type="text/javascript">
var trigger = [
  ["hi","hey","hello"], 
  ["how are you", "how is life", "how are things"],
  ["what are you doing", "what is going on"]
];
var reply = [
  ["Hi","Hey","Hello"], 
  ["Fine", "Pretty well", "Fantastic"],
  ["Nothing much", "About to go to sleep", "Can you guest?", "I don't know actually"],
];

var alternative = ["Haha...", "Eh..."];
console.log('a');
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if(key === 13){ //Enter button
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = input;
    output(input);
  }
});
function output(input){
  try{
    var product = input + "=" + eval(input);
  } catch(e){
    var text = (input.toLowerCase()).replace(/[^\w\s\d]/gi, ""); //remove all chars except words, space and 
    text = text.replace(/ a /g, " ").replace(/i feel /g, "").replace(/whats/g, "what is").replace(/please /g, "").replace(/ please/g, "");
    if(compare(trigger, reply, text)){
      var product = compare(trigger, reply, text);
    } else {
      var product = alternative[Math.floor(Math.random()*alternative.length)];
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("system").innerHTML = product;
  speak(product);
  document.getElementById("input").value = ""; //clear input value
}
function compare(arr, array, string){
  var item;
  for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
    for(var y=0; y<array.length; y++){
      if(arr[x][y] == string){
        items = array[x];
        item =  items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
      }
    }
  }
  return item;
}

function speak(string){

}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really apperciate this, but is there a way to do this without changing the DOM or the code itself? Is there something I can just add in? If not It's okay! I'm just wondering. Much thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah I've added the new code in my answer. Your JavaScript code works well. I just added some HTML elements so your code can read or write to it. You probably don't need the `speak()` function since you've already used the line `document.getElementById("system").innerHTML = product;` to display the response.